# C#, json .net - value of the two words

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Need to parse JSON like this:

```
{
  "Status": "Success",
  "Data": {
    "Folders": [
      {
        "Folder ID": 1,
        "Name": "12"
      },
      {
        "Folder ID": 2,
        "Name": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Doing as:

```
public class getFoldersDataFolders
{
    public int FolderID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class getFoldersDataAnswer
{
    public List<getFoldersDataFolders> Folders { get; set; }
}

public class getFoldersAnswer
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public getFoldersDataAnswer Data { get; set; }
}
...
    var gfA = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WAAPIJSONClasses.getFoldersAnswer>( answer );
    for ( var i = 0; i < gfA.Data.Folders.Count; i++ )
    {
        folders[ gfA.Data.Folders[ i ].Name ] = gfA.Data.Folders[ i ].FolderID;
    }
```

in gfA.Data.Folders[ i ].FolderID i have 0.

I think the problem is that the name of the field "Folder ID" consists of two words (separated by spaces).
So, how to get the value of the field if the field name contains multiple words (separated by spaces)?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to:

```
public class getFoldersDataFolders
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Folder ID")]
    public int FolderID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```